# Committee forming: bad intuition, but where?

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

Consider the following problem:

> How many different mixed gender committees of 3 people can be chosen
>   from a group of 5 men and 5 women?

**Wrong approach**: These are committees of the form $M_1M_2W_1$ or $W_1W_2M_1$ (the ordering does not matter). 
There are $5\choose 2$$5\choose 1$ of the former and  $5\choose 2$$5\choose 1$ of the latter for a total of $2{5\choose 2}{5\choose 1}=100$ possible committee.

**Correct approach**: Take the total number of committees of 3 possible and subtract from the number of non-mixed ones. There are ${10\choose 3}$ possible committees and ${3\choose 5}$ all men (and as many all women) ones. Therefore, one gets ${10\choose 3}-2{5\choose 3}=80$ possible committees.

Here is my question: The first approach over-counts 20 committees. I wonder of what form are these over counted committees. More generally, I fail to understand why the first approach gives an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are correct, but you have evaluated the result of the second approach incorrectly. It should be
\begin{equation}
\binom{10}{3} - 2\,\binom{5}{3} = 120 - 2\times 10 = 100,
\end{equation}
which agrees with the result of the first approach. So, this was just a calculation error.

Comment: Argh: sorry, the correct approach was from a book and of course, I didn't check their calculations (they put the expression in terms of combinatorial and the final answer only)!